# automatically generate string from data frame row

Tags: r

I am trying to create a string from a data frame row. So my little example is this:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c('bla'), firstname=c('dada'), other=c('dum'))
sprintf('name:%s firstname:%s other:%s',
        df[1,'name'],
        df[1,'firstname'],
        df[1,'other'])
```

I am trying to create a function which I can provide the data frame as an argument and creates the string as I like.

I started to try this with `sprintf` but I can't get the arguments right:

```
sprintf(paste(sub('$',':%s',names(df)), collapse=' '), df[1,])
```

How can I unlist or anyhow automatically use the arguments? The working solution would be:

```
sprintf(paste(sub('$',':%s',names(df)), collapse=' '), 
        df[1,'name'],
        df[1,'firstname'],
        df[1,'other'])
```

Comment: To make it automatic, you can use `fmt <- paste0(names(df), ':%s', collapse=' ')` and then use the function in @AnandaMahto's post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps `do.call` would help:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c('bla'), firstname=c('dada'), other=c('dum'))
fmt <- 'name:%s firstname:%s other:%s'
do.call(sprintf, c(df, fmt = fmt))
# [1] "name:bla firstname:dada other:dum"
```